# Product of Hausdorff measures of different dimensions

Tags: measure-theory, geometric-measure-theory, hausdorff-measure

I have some questions about constructing a single measure from two Hausdorff measures of different dimensions.
Let us define the indicator function $f:[0,1]\times[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ of the diagonal line by $$f(p,q)=\begin{cases}1&\text{if }p=q\\0&\text{otherwise.}\end{cases} $$

We can now measure the length $\mathcal{L}(f)$ of the line projected to the first dimension by
$$\mathcal{L}(f) = \int_{[0,1]}\int_{[0,1]}f(p,q)\ d\mathcal{H}^0q\ \  d\mathcal{H}^1p\text{,}$$
where $\mathcal{H}^0$ and $\mathcal{H}^1$ are the $0$-dimensional and $1$-dimensional Hausdorff measures, respectively.

1. Is it correct that the integrals evaluate to $1$ (i.e. $\mathcal{L}(f)=1$)?
2. Is it correct that the two integrals do not commute and Fubini's theorem does not hold because $\mathcal{H}^0$ is not $\sigma$-finite?
3. It is possible to construct a measure $\mu$ on $[0,1]\times[0,1]$ such that
   $$\int_{[0,1]}\int_{[0,1]}f(p,q)\ d\mathcal{H}^0q\ \  d\mathcal{H}^1p=\int_{[0,1]\times[0,1]}f(p,q)\ d\mu(p,q)\text{?}$$
   Is there a definition of product measures that does this job (like $\mu=\mathcal{H}^1\times\mathcal{H}^0$)? What would be a good read on this?

I would be really happy if someone could answer the questions, especially Q3. :-)

Comment: [Related.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2244312/does-the-graph-of-a-measurable-function-always-have-zero-measure)

Comment: Thank you Daniel for pointing to the related question. As mentioned in the answer in the related question, if one measure is not $\sigma$-finite the product measure is not uniquely defined. Furthermore the example in Wikipedia [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_measure] states that the diagonal has measure $0$ in the case of the minimal product measure and $\infty$ in the case of maximal product measure. My question is essentially if one can define a product measure that gives you a value of $1$ for the diagonal.